# Does the equation of ball going up in gravity straight up with a vertical initial velocity hold when it's coming down?

Tags: equations-of-motion

Suppose a ball is thrown up and having the same altitude at different times. So should the equation of motion $ v_0t - gt^2$ which I derive from balancing forces hold for both the times when the ball is going up and coming down.

[image]

Comment: perhaps there is a factor of (1/2) in the 2nd term. and the sign of acceleration has to change in the two  parts of the motion.

Comment: Hint : an equation should be of the form a=b.

Comment: @dvrm gravity does not change sign.

Comment: @my2cts the two times are given when the ball has gained the same altitude.  I can equalize two equations and get a relation between them. But can I take the same eom while ascending and descending.

Comment: Yes, the EOM is the same up and down $v=v_o-gt$ but it is not clear why you are throwing the ball more than once.

Comment: @safesphere I am writing with reference to the question. Which I right now attached with the question.

Comment: @safesphere anyway does the same eom hold for both cases of ascending and descending of the ball?

Comment: Yes, as I already stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of e.g quadratic resistive forces $\sim -k v^2 \hat v $, the equation of motion for the ball is the same in both segments of its trajectory, up and down. This is because the only force acting on the ball is gravity which points downwards in both segments.

With an additional damping force present of the form above, in one segment this force is pointing in the same direction as gravity and in the other segment it points oppositely so the force balance has to be altered accordingly.